# How to show PDF character layer again in Document Viewer when selecting text?

Tags: fedora, pdf

After updating from Fedora 33 to 34 I noticed that PDF files with text layer behave differently in [Evince Document Viewer](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince).

When selecting text the **old** version used to display the characters above the image. The **new** version only shows the selection box but not the characters anymore.

Here's an example:

**Fedora 33 with Document Viewer 3.38.2:**

[image]

See the selected "cksend" being put **on top of** the actual image?

**Fedora 34 with Document Viewer 40.4** skips the characters and just shows the selected part of the word:

[image]

How can I get the old behavior back? How can I see the actual characters again?

I'm asking because I'm creating those PDFs using [ocrmypdf](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the visible layer of characters allowed me to inspect the correctness of the output. Incorrect characters were immediately visible. With the new version I cannot see this anymore. So how can I get my characters back?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the poppler upgrade from 0.90.0 (Fedora 33) to 21.x (Fedora 34) caused the new rendering behavior (regardless of the Document Viewer version).

Downgrading poppler restores the old behavior:

`sudo dnf --allowerasing --releasever 33 --disablerepo \* --enablerepo updates downgrade poppler`

(Just need to make sure that it's not upgraded again the next time updates are installed.)